# Android studio Failed to create jvm

Tags: java, android, jvm

Failed to create JVM : error code -4.
JVM Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
If you have already have a 32-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable

Comment: after setting both path in JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
Now it says "The environemt variable JAVA_HOME (with the value of C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 ) does not point to a valid JVM installation"

Comment: updated my jdk and android studio and its start working

Comment: I have [answered on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532284/5376073) what was working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem

- Only put one source in JAVA_HOME . example.C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0.79\jre
- even that didnt worked try changing this file called studio.exe.vmoptions(32bit) and studio64.exe.vmoptions(64bit) which is situated in the installation directory of android studio\bin . change the line called -Xmx750m to -Xmx512m, it worked for me

Hope it would be useful

if any doubts please mention