# Error launching Android Studio: Failed to create JVM: error code-6

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jvm

I install Android Studio and run normally. But because it was a bit slow so I follow instructions from the website: [How can you do when Android Studio was slow](https://viblo.asia/cuasodayleo/posts/Q7eERE5gRgNj) and It made me unable to reopen android studio though I have tried to uninstall and reinstall AS well as Java. I use Android studio 2.1, Windows 8.1, core i3, RAM 4 GB.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - No JVM Installation found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898684/android-studio-no-jvm-installation-found)

Comment: my error has gone, have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616303/failed-to-create-jvmerror-code-6-android-studio/41678833#41678833

Comment: I have also [answered on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532284/5376073) what was working for me.

Comment: if you meets this problem by changing studio64.exe.vmoptions.   
restore it.

Answer (score 39):

just go this directory:

C:\Users\{pc name}

and delete all folders starting with .AndroidStudio

This solves the issue.

Comment: I have .AndroidStudio1.5 and .AndroidStudio2.2 which one should we remove

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: In Android Studio 3 you must remove .AndroidStudio3 folder and problem will solved . thanks

Comment: removing **studio64.exe.vmoptions** does the work, no need to remove the whole folder. as mentioned by Wasim and Satya Attili

Answer (score 15):

Please cross check VMoptions **filestudio64.exe.vmoptions** file or delete the studio64.exe.vmoptions from the location C:\Users\pcname.AndroidStudioX.Y

Answer (score 8):

If you have updated or created ***studio64.exe.vmoptions***  which present at the location {$user}/.AndroidStudio$version. 
Delete the file

Comment: For android studio 4.1 path is different:  
**C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\studio64.exe.vmoptions**   

And yes, that file caused the error on start.  
Thank you, **@Wasim**

Answer (score 1):

You should:
- Use Windowx x64 (64 bit, because your computer has 4GB RAM).
- Use lastest JDK (1.8 update 92, x64) for Windows
- **Important:**
Press combination keys: <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or **Run** utility.
type: `systempropertiesadvanced`
[image]
[image][image]
[image]
[image]

set environment variable:
`JAVA_HOME` directory where JDK installed.
add to `PATH` variable: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Comment: Not Working these settings had been already done before, the error occured suddenly

Answer (score 0):

Delete this file **studio64.exe.vmoptions** inside

`C:\Users\%USER%\.AndroidStudio{version}\config`

Answer (score 0):

I have had set JAVA_HOME variable appropriately but that didn't work for me. The only thing that worked was running `studio.bat` file inside `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin`. So, you can set shortcut target to point to the studio.bat file.

NOTES:

- I am using OpenJDK (Installed via AdoptOpenJDK)
- Android Studio version is 4.1.2

Answer (score -1):

This problem can occur if there is something like a comment in the red box,so you should delete it.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/64RYL.png]