# Failed to create JVM : error code -6 in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am using windows 8.1

here is the error

[image: here is the eror]

cmd seems to see the java -version but not my android studio.

here is my system variable

[image: here is my system variable]

Comment: I have [answered on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532284/5376073) what was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidStudio is not asking for a JDK, but for a JRE. Try changing the JAVA_HOME to the JRE bundled in the JDK:

> C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre

If above don't work, try with:

> C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin

If neither of them works, check if your JDK is a 64-bit one since the AndroidStudio is asking for a 64-bit java version.

EDITING:
Also try copying the content of C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre because it seems that AndroidStudio is checking for java in that path.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the studio64.exe.vmoptions under C:\Users...AndroidStudio3.2\config.

Answer (score 0):

edit the project's `gradle.properties` and add:

```
org.gradle.java.home = C\:\\Program\ Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_131
```