# Failed to create JVM: error code -1

Tags: android, android-studio

ERROR:

> Failed to create JVM: error code -1. JVM Path: C:\Program Files\android\android studio\jre\jre If you a;ready have a 64-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in the Environmetal Variables.

Things I've done:

1. Edited the studio64.exe.vmoptions -Lessen the size of xmx and xms
2. Deleted the studio64.exe.vmoptions in the Users/UserName/AndroidStudio3.1/bin
3. Changed the the PATH AND JAVA_HOME paths to their respective paths.

JDK Version: 10.2 
Android Studio Version: 3.1.4

Comment: I doubt Android supports Java 10 yet

Comment: echo %JAVA_HOME% check this to find if the same is getting reflected. If something else is showing  like C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath remove those from path variable

Comment: I have [answered on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532284/5376073) what was working for me.