# Error launching Studio- JAVA_HOME - Failed to create JVM.JVM path

Tags: android-studio, launching-application

I get the following error:
[image: Error]

I tried the advises from other posts but it did not worked. I made a JAVA_HOME variable in both user and system but it still doesn't work.
[image: Variable and path]

Comment: I have [answered on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532284/5376073) what was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by deleting the studio64.exe.vmoptions in C:\Users#username.AndroidStudio3.5\config